# How to fix the script to work on certain sheet only in the onOpen function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a line of code in a google sheet that print the current date in cell `C1` when there is an user open the google sheet. This is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,3).setValue(new Date())
}
```

There are multiple tabs in the google sheet, so the code is actually printing the date in any tab depends on the first arrival of user when they open the google sheet. For example, if the user first arrived at `Sheet2` when they open the google sheet, the date will be printed on `Sheet2` cell `C1` instead of `Sheet1` cell `C1`.

May I know how should I modified the code so that it only print the date in `Sheet1` even though the active sheet is `Sheet2` when I open the google sheet? Hope to get some advice, any help will be geatly appreciated!

Comment: Use getSheetByName() which is available in Class  Spreadsheet

Comment: I had tried `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,3).setValue(new Date())`, but it didn't print the date on either `Sheet1` or  `Sheet2`, where did I did wrong?

Comment: I'm quite new to the google apps script, so I don't understand about `Class` concept that you mentioned, I will take a look on that, thank you.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp identify what type of document it is, getActive(), getActiveSheet(), getByID() is the active file, then getSheetByName(), or getSheet(index) gets the specific sheet, and lastly getRange() is the set of cells.

Comment: If `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,3).setValue(new Date())` didn't work then something strange is going on. Are you sure that your sheet is named exactly `Sheet1`? Did you make sure to run it from the script editor first to give it permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get it by using:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,3).setValue(new Date())
}
```